# How to fix this error in order()?

Tags: r

Here is my code:

```
rankhospital <- function(state, outcome){
    o<-17
    out<-data.frame(out)
    out.sub<-subset(out,State==state)
    out.s<-subset(out.sub[,c(1,2,7,o)])
    out.1<-out.s[!out.sub["Lower.Mortality.Estimate...Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure"]=="Not Available",]
    sor<-order(as.numeric(out.1[,4]))
    x<-out.1[sor,]
    x
}
```

My function reads a `.csv` file and sorts it based on the values in the 4th column and return the sorted data.frame through `x` but the output of it is like this:

```
10.1
10.1
10.1
10.2
10.2
...
...
...
6.3
6.4
6.5
...
9.0
9.3
...
```

It seems that `order` is not ordering my values in the 4th column of `out.1`

How to fix this??

Thank you

Comment: What is `out.1[,4]` ? Given your code, I guess it's a factor. If it is, the issue could come from its transformation to numeric, which doesn't work that way.

Comment: @Vincent i want to order the 4 th column of out.1 so i used `out.1[,4]`

Comment: Yes I get it but I wonder what is in this column. Is it a vector of factors ? (my guess) Of numerics ? Of characters ?

Comment: @Vincent the column contains character which i ma converting it to numerics while ordering

Comment: My guess was wrong then. Could you provide a reproducible example so we can better see what happens ?

Comment: There is little doubt that the stuff that's being ordered is still `character`, not `numeric` (or possibly still a `factor`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain that `class(out.1)=="factor"` and when doing `as.numeric()` on factors, you get the underlying integer codes, not the values of the labels converted to numbers. Try changing the line to

```
sor<-order(as.numeric(as.character(out.1[,4])))
```

and remember to be very careful with your different column class types. Factors are not the same as character vectors.